# How to measure how long a signal takes to change CAPL

Tags: capl, canoe

I'm using a VN1630 and I'm trying to measure how long a LIN signal takes to change based on when the digital input signal flips from 0 to 1 on the VN1630.

How can I measure this in CAPL?

Answer (score 1):

Use CAPL functions:

- `on signal/sysvar`  - to catch signal/sysvar(IO) change
- `timeNow()` - to get the current simulation time

Catch the IO switch, take time, catch the signal switch, take time, calculate time difference.